# How to pass an external argument to reduce callback?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a reduce function on an array, and I'd like to pass it an external argument (`some_variable` here):

```js
const myCallback = (x, y) => {
  return x + y*some_variable
}

function myFunction() {
  let some_variable = 2;
  [1, 2, 3].reduce(myCallback, 0); 
}

myFunction(); // should return 12
```

I tried to use `.bind`, `.apply`, but it messes up with the own x/y arguments of the callback. I suspect I would have to use closures or something like that, but I don't really understand these things.

Is there a way to do this ?
Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Consider using currying? `myCallback = (some_variable) => (x, y) => {` which you can use like `reduce(myCallback(2),0)` --- I think this is currying at least...

Comment: This particular code should work as is… Is `myCallback` defined somewhere else? Then you'd want a function which takes `some_variable` and returns the actual reducer function. From the caller side it would look like `.reduce(myCallback(some_variable), 0)`, and `myCallback` would need to *return a function*.

Comment: Yes you are right deceze, it worked as it was here. But actually if you call the reduce in an other function it returns a `some_variable is not defined`. I changed my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return the *reducer function* from `myCallback`, using the extra parameter from the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```js
const myCallback = something => {
  return (x, y) => x + y * something;
  //     ^ return function |
  //                       ^ something is known from the closure
};

console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce(myCallback(0), 0));
//                                      ^ 'something'
console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce(myCallback(1), 0));
console.log([1, 2, 3].reduce(myCallback(2), 0));
```